# How to aggregate 1-minute data to 30-minutes or 1-hour average data in dolphindb

Tags: window, quantitative-finance, dolphindb

I have a stock data which is ordered by minute, I want to aggregate the 1-minute data to 30-minutes or 1-hour average data. I contextby stock_code first, then invoke function rolling to aggregate. But it does't work. The code is:

```
mins_data = select rolling(first, code, 15,15) as Code,rolling(first, time_all, 15,15) as time 
, rolling(first, open, 15, 15) as Open, rolling(max, high, 15,15) as High, rolling(min, low, 
15, 15) as Low, rolling(last, close, 15, 15) as Close, rolling(sum, volume, 15, 15) as Volume, 
rolling(sum, turnover, 15, 15) as Turnover from mins_data context by code;
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The k-line data can be realized by 'group by code, date, bar(time,...)'. For specific examples, please refer to the [k-line tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_en/blob/master/OHLC.md)